# Concat 2 tables with different structure using linq

Tags: c#, linq, union, concatenation

I would like to union 2 tables and display all in a datagrid:

- tblReservation (ID, StartTime, EndTime, SchoolID, AccomodationID)
- tblMeeting (ID, StartTime, EndTime, Subject, Location)

In the datagrid I have 2 matching columns (StartTime, EndTime) and 2 different columns. Still I want to unite these 2 tables and set column 3 for School/Subject and column 4 for Accomodation/Location.

In PHP I know you can set names for the fields you get by using

```
SELECT x AS name
```

but I am not very familiar with the LINQ-syntax.

Here I get the data from tblReservation from the date I've selected in the month calendar:

```
var vReservation = (from oReservation in clsApplication._oDBConnection.tblReservations
    where oReservation.StartTime.Value.Date >= mcCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.Date
    && oReservation.StartTime.Value.Date < cCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.Date.AddHours(24)
    orderby oReservation.StartTime ascending
    select oReservation);

foreach (var oReservation in vReservation)
{
    build the datagrid
}
```

How can I add the other table to this loop?

Comment: when say mathcing and different do you mean type or value?

Comment: I say different because School and Accomadation are being saved with their ID

Answer (score 0):

in select you can do something like

```
select new { oReservation.StartTime, oRservation.EndTime };
```

And then use the Union() extension method passing the other query to get them together
See the 2nd box [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following entities;

```
public class tblReservation
{
    public tblReservation(int id, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, int schoolID, int accomodationID)
    {
    ID = id;
    StartTime = startTime;
    EndTime = endTime;
    SchoolID = schoolID;
    AccomodationID = accomodationID;
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }
    public int AccomodationID { get; set; }
}
public class tblMeeting
{
    public tblMeeting(int id, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, string subject, string location)
    {
    ID = id;
    StartTime = startTime;
    EndTime = endTime;
    Subject = subject;
    Location = location;
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

And i have filled these entities with dummy data as shown below;

```
 var tblReservations = new List<tblReservation>() { new tblReservation(1,DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(1),1,1), new tblReservation(2, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(2), 2, 3) };
        var tblMeetings = new List<tblMeeting>() { new tblMeeting(1, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(1),"subject1","location1"), new tblMeeting(2, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(2), "subject2", "location2") } ;
```

And the following LINQ will give the result as you want.

```
var result = tblReservations.Join(tblMeetings, x => string.Concat(x.StartTime,x.EndTime), y => string.Concat(y.StartTime,y.EndTime), (x, y) => new { x, y })
            .Select(m => new tblMeeting(m.x.ID, m.x.StartTime, m.x.EndTime, string.Concat(m.x.SchoolID, "/", m.y.Subject), string.Concat(m.x.AccomodationID, "/", m.y.Location)));
```

I have used **tblMeeting** as a result type,if you want you can create a new type as you wish.